# When to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in windows phone project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I am starting with a new project based on `MVVM` approach.I will be loading some data asynchronously from some web service.I am confused about where to implement this `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface,in a viewmodel,model or both.
Also If I implement INotifyPropertyChanged on a model(let's call it ModelA).Then I create an `ObservableCollection<ModelA>`,Will not it be redundant as `ObservableCollection` itself keeps track of any data change made to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` class only updates UI in case of following operations:

- Item is added in collection.
- Item is deleted from collection.
- Collection is clear.

But if any `property changes in underlying item` i.e. `ModelA` in your case, it `won't be reflected on UI` unless your Model class is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raising PropertyChanged event on property change.

So, as a thumb rule you should implement `INPC` both at your `ViewModel` layer and also at `Model` layer.

Comment: Glad to help Rajat. Hope your query is resloeved :)

Answer (score 1):

Practically you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to objects which property will be displayed in UI using data binding. If you bind the UI directly to property of your model then you need to implement it in the model too.

ObservableCollection only notify UI when object added or removed from collection. To get the UI notified when property of one or more objects in that ObservableCollection changed you still need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in that object class.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. If you need your model to implement INotifyPropertyChanged then it should. Redundant or not if you need to keep track on a single property you will be better of using that event rather than the ObservableCollection.